# Angular build ignore typescript error using noImplicitAny is not working

Tags: angular, typescript

Recently, I need to upgrade my angular project from v6 to v10, and I found huge amount of ts errors, one is the property not exist error.

In Typescript2, this is ignored, so our application can build with no issue, but ng10 is using typescript3, and this is not allowed.

I checked angular doc, and set tsconfig.json as below:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": ["es6", "es7", "es2017", "dom"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "types": [],
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "strict": false
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

You can see the noImplicitAny is false, and suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors is true, but still have a lot errors like this:

```
error TS2339: Property 'webkitRequestFullscreen' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.
```

Can anyone help to tell me when you upgrade your ng6 to higher level angular version, have you met this issue and how do you resolve it?

Going to each file to fix is not possible since our project is way too big.

Thanks and waiting for hear your advice.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me the errors you are getting are caught on properties of objects that have an explicit type defined, instead of any.

After all you are using Typescript, it is best practice to try and work with types as much as possible and avoid using 'any'. Getting a property from a type where it does not exist on will not work.

Comment: Thanks, my question is can we ignore these type of checking and let all pass as that of typescript2? We can fix these gradually, but we do not want the upgrade taking months to finish. Thanks for your advice

Comment: Seeing as the upgrade would take so long, the fastest way to do it would be to cast every object where the error gets thrown to `any` using `as any`. Probably not the cleanest solution however.